# Usage of JL and JLE in this case?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm just a novice at assembly programming. I have an integer `a`. I was trying to understand if there was any performance difference between

```
if(a >= 0)
```

and

```
if(a > -1)
```

So, I proceeded to disassemble the above. In my x86 machine,

```
if(a >= 0)
```

Disassembles to:

```
cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4],0
jl          main+43h (00401053)
```

And,

```
if(a > -1)
```

Disassembles to:

```
cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFh
jle         main+43h (00401053)
```

I can quickly write a program that calculates CPU cycles for these programs (haven't done that yet). BUT, I now am faced with a different issue.

I understand that `cmp` will perform a `sub` and set the `SF`, `ZF`, `PF`, `CF`, `OF` and/or `AF` flags appropriately. I also understand that a `jl` will check for the `SF <> OF` criteria. **What is the `<>` operator here?**

[The reference I used](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) said that `jl` will load `EIP` with the specified argument if, for a `cmp arg2, arg1`,

1. arg2 < arg1 and the operation does not have overflow
2. arg2 < arg1 and the operation has an overflow

The reference also says `jl` will not jump when `arg2 == arg1`.

My second question is, shouldn't `jl` jump when `arg2 <= arg1` in the case of `if(a <= 0)` and when `arg2 < arg1` in the case of `if(a < -1)`?

Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: The jumps are done when the condition is false. They jump to the else (or, if absent, past the `if`).

Comment: @DanielFischer, Oh man. Thanks! That cleared that doubt. But what is the `<>` operator?

Comment: My guess is "not equal". But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<>` operator means "*not equal*", i.e. the same as `!=` in C.

> shouldn't jl jump when arg2 <= arg1 in the case of if(a <= 0)

Your condition is `a >= 0`, not `a <= 0`. What the `jl` does is skip the chunk of code that would be executed if `a >= 0`.

I.e. something like this:

```
cmp a,0   
jl end_if  ; jump past the body of the if-statement if the condition is false,
           ; i.e. a < 0
; code that should be executed if a >= 0 goes here
; ...
end_if:
```